# API para consulta de lugares no mapa

Tags: c#, .net, rest, windows-phone, maps

Estou precisando de uma API que funcione como o HERE Maps, que possibilita uma consulta fácil através de um serviço REST. Com ele consigo por exemplo, identificar lojas dentro de um certo raio de alcance. Mas me deparei com o problema de que ele não fornece essas informações quando por exemplo, as lojas estão dentro de um shopping.

O Bing Maps tem essa informação quando acessado pelo navegador. Mas ainda não consegui identificar como fazer isso através da API.

Alguém sabe como resolver isso?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O [`Google Places`](https://developers.google.com/places/webservice/search) possui REST Services para consulta de lugares, além de outras APIs, como JavaScript.

É possível consultar por pontos (latitude e longitude), endereço e como você citou, buscar lojas em determinando raio (ou seja, por tipos específicos de estabelecimentos). Vários tipos de lugares são suportados e você pode ver a lista dos tipos neste link: [tipos de lugares](https://developers.google.com/places/supported_types).

Como exemplo, segue uma consulta por lojas (**store**) consumindo o WS REST do Google Places e retornando JSON. Vou usar o ponto central de Florianópolis (`lat=-27.6142358;lng=-48.4828247`) retornado pelo Google Maps e um raio de 200 metros.

Os parâmetros serão:

```
location: -27.6142358,-48.4828247
radius: 200
language: pt-BR
type: store
key: {sua_api_key}
```

Para informação sobre a chave de API, veja neste link: [Google API Key](https://developers.google.com/console/help/#generatingdevkeys)

Com estes parâmetros a URL resultante será a seguinte:

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?location=-27.6142358,-48.4828247&radius=200&language=pt-BR&type=store&key={sua_api_key}
```

Para esta pesquisa o resultado foi este:

```js
{
   "html_attributions" : [],
   "results" : [
      {
         "geometry" : {
            "location" : {
               "lat" : -27.615584,
               "lng" : -48.484707
            }
         },
         "icon" : "http://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/place_api/icons/wine-71.png",
         "id" : "d4068353334ad7655800b0e4a7908e15b882a404",
         "name" : "ALE BEBIDAS",
         "opening_hours" : {
            "open_now" : true,
            "weekday_text" : []
         },
         "place_id" : "ChIJBxuO5lE5J5UR9u9xCVWhfEg",
         "reference" : "CmReAAAAOVtoo1S_NPy2AcKW4FcXqXVlCmUIuTIIccZP0F6qt8KDKqDHfRm7Ng8SeXRqsGPmo8e_846R-PRCe1KZyLkl9VZVsfIIMdoaIxG86BWH0KNLR8gzvUiUhdFxgbUHYB1pEhBzTzPE0vAr4w6uolz7dKSBGhRbzJls4F2xRH83i7ypdcvdRtXdvA",
         "scope" : "GOOGLE",
         "types" : [ "liquor_store", "store", "establishment" ],
         "vicinity" : "Rua Laurindo Januário da Silveira, 2452 - Lagoa da Conceição, Florianópolis"
      },
      {
         "geometry" : {
            "location" : {
               "lat" : -27.615853,
               "lng" : -48.484668
            }
         },
         "icon" : "http://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/place_api/icons/wine-71.png",
         "id" : "cdb56aaa10f3a9458d66db2cef5cc883ee197195",
         "name" : "Central de Bebidas Canto da Lagoa",
         "opening_hours" : {
            "open_now" : false,
            "weekday_text" : []
         },
         "place_id" : "ChIJJ2Ot6FE5J5URtqcR1cfFqFc",
         "reference" : "CoQBdAAAAEoaG4QA0oGjWHBMjj7OGoiP8SEtfZbDb8eKe1O-2csV3Kpx-zqZ83RdBvgZwvCj66_0_XDuNUmMMfEbjP2nDcM9FR5MxcUhVSKjc4b26N5hd3057Wf40B2uhE56l14QWo3RhfTnGxEs0KU_dWtlCE2xGaUyo0zW0EaG3NspmVNyEhA5iHD9_3ABWqupiCGDcciKGhS7bVKHoO1Im47kbn7yWyR0f_-c4g",
         "scope" : "GOOGLE",
         "types" : [ "liquor_store", "store", "establishment" ],
         "vicinity" : "Rua Laurindo Januário da Silveira, 2.460 - Lagoa da Conceição, Florianópolis"
      },
      {
         "geometry" : {
            "location" : {
               "lat" : -27.615299,
               "lng" : -48.484732
            }
         },
         "icon" : "http://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/place_api/icons/generic_business-71.png",
         "id" : "2e4c65a1d61c72d0b64b6044645c58f1a3f3e13d",
         "name" : "Hiper Bom",
         "place_id" : "ChIJa0_q4VE5J5UR3kiEd-J2FL4",
         "reference" : "CmRdAAAAKQgXto7LtfDAb7RbkWybZ5djSo_4hdr7Y5waV7uF3EuGPt1vE-n3pvFKhkeJAPy2WPoK-TMSGqQSw9oJ3sCCUGF4aQgA85BsBZup3qz10O7ack30cay0imQx7FCr02ITEhDuG3WwOOPnEhBCUMx2rlo6GhSkxbL6YMVwdmqOFLhMzs6PztikHA",
         "scope" : "GOOGLE",
         "types" : [ "grocery_or_supermarket", "food", "store", "establishment" ],
         "vicinity" : "Rua Laurindo Januário da Silveira, 2420 - Lagoa da Conceição, Florianópolis"
      }
   ],
   "status" : "OK"
}
```

Veja [neste](https://developers.google.com/places/webservice/search#PlaceSearchResponses) link o significado de cada atributo retornado, além do que ele pode retornar.

Não conheço o Bing Maps muito bem, é possível que ele tenha também este serviço. Sei que existem dados públicos para consulta pela `Bing Spatial Data Services`. como para a América do Norte, através do [`NAVTEQNA`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh478192.aspx) e Europa, através do [`NAVTEQEU`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh478193.aspx). Não sei se há algo no Brasil ou outras regiões.

Existem outros serviços também, como a do [Foursquare](https://developer.foursquare.com/start/search) que talvez ofereça busca por raio também, você consegue encontrar outras referências facilmente na internet. Ficam citadas estas duas e o exemplo do Google Places que acredito ser a mais utilizada.

Comment: Obrigado por sua resposta Bruno. Estou utilizando o Google Place, pois ele se encaixa dentro do que estou precisando. Só queria outra alternativa, com toda essa treta que rola de vez em quando entre Google e Microsoft fico com o pé atrás em utilizá-lo. Mas ta servindo. O Bing até utilizei, mas acho que não serve. Vou dar uma olhada no Foursquare também, não sabia que dava pra utilizá-lo.